# Is it possible to add custom CSS to a WebView in Xamarin using ONLY ONE stylesheet in my Assets folder?

Tags: android, ios, css, xamarin, webview

I've seen multiple [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938928/i-need-to-load-html-and-css-different-from-android-and-ios-from-a-file-and-dis) adding a GetBaseUrl separately for IOS and Android, but they don't answer my question. I was wondering if there is  no other way to add custom CSS to a webview and only use 1 stylesheet (default.css). The reason why I want to do this is because my stylesheet is identical for both IOS and Android and contains little styling.

This is what I've tried:
I have a WebView:

```
 <WebView.Source >
        <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding Data.Content}" />
    </WebView.Source>
```

The Source of this WebView is a string that looks like this:

```
string  contentString =   @"<html>
                            <head>" +
                            "<link rel='stylesheet' href='default.css'" 
                            "</head>" +
                            "<body style='text-align:left;background-color:white;font-size:16px;margin:0;'>" +
                            value +
                            "</body>" +
                            "</html>";
```

The **default.css**  file mentioned above is in my Assets folder and has Build Action EmbeddedResource, located in the root directory of my project:

[image: e]

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is an assembly-based embedded resource, read it out of the assembly as a string and inline it into your html in-between a `<style>`  tag

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I do not know how to do this. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to do this, one is to use HtmlWebViewSource, the html is like this:

```
htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
<head>
<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""default.css"">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
<p>The CSS and image are loaded from local files!</p>
<img src='XamarinLogo.png'/>
<p><a href=""local.html"">next page</a></p>
</body>
</html>";
```

Another way is to use WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL, there is the same thread that you can take a look:

[Rendering HTML in a WebView with custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to wrap your HTML with CSS (or replace **link tags** with its resulting content)

```
var html = AddHtmlAndCssTags("<div>my html</div>", ReadCss());





protected string ReadCss()
{
    var resourceName = $"MyProj.Resources.Css.article.css";
    var isExists = ResourceLoader.IsEmbeddedResourceExists(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ResourceLoader)), resourceName);

    if (isExists)
    {
        return ResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceString(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ResourceLoader)), resourceName);
    }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    protected string AddHtmlAndCssTags(string html, string css)
    {
        var cssTag = string.IsNullOrEmpty(css) ? string.Empty : $"<style>{css}</style>";
        return $"<html><head>{cssTag}</head><body>{html}<body></html>";
    }
```