# Loading an html asset that's stored within Xamarin.Forms into a webview

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I read in an existing question on how to use a [webview in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45100122/25282) that suggests to write platform specific code on every supported platform.

Ideally, I want to store my html in a file within `/assets/` in the Xamarin.Forms instead of storing it once for every OS.

I desire to have an easier way and simply store the asset within Xamarin.Forms. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you facing the same issue as the other questioner?

Comment: @G.hakim : No, the other questioner wants a solution that works on Android `This only needs to be done through Android so there is no worries about about IOS and Windows.` I want reduce complexity along multiple OS.

Comment: So you want a cross-platform solution for the same question?

Comment: @G.hakim : Yes.

Comment: Can you share a little light on how is your html asset stored? is it as an object or as a file?

Comment: @G.hakim : Okay, I edited my question.

Comment: I have added an answer as per my understanding of the question take a look and let me know if i missed something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to get it to work:

In `RightClickOnProject/Properties/Resources` there's a view that allows to add files that can be used as resources within Xamarin.Forms. I added there a `HtmlFile.txt`-file.

I add the WebView to the `xaml` via:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="Web" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />                     
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Then in the code-behind I do:

```
public partial class OurPage: ContentPage
{
    public OurPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Web.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource{Html = Properties.Resources.HtmlFile};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am correct you can sort of do it using an Embedded file in the asset folder and then reading it using `System.IO` something like this (Assuming you are using a NET Standard assembly):

- Add the file that you want to read into the desired folder in your portable class and also ensure that the 
  **Build Action: EmbeddedResource**.
- Then use `GetManifestResourceStream` to access the embedded file using its Resource ID, By default, the resource ID is the filename prefixed with the default namespace for the project it is embedded in - in this case, the assembly is `WorkingWithFiles` and the filename is PCLTextResource.txt, so the resource ID is WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt. Now to get the desired file data all you need to so is something like this:

  ```
   var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
   Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");
   string text = "";
   using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
   text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
   }
  ```

  Where `LoadResourceText` is the cs file in which I am using this code to get the current assembly. Note that this should be the same assembly where the Embedded resource that you have just added is present and `WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt` is the Assembly path for your Embedded resource for eg: If your assembly name is `Foo` and your file is in a folder called `Asset` then your path for this would be something like `Foo.Asset.Your_File.txt`
- Once you are done with all this then the easy part begins, in your WebView page define a `HtmlWebViewSource` and assign it as the source to your WebView and Vola! you have loaded the data from the file your file.

  ```
      var browser = new WebView();
      var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
      htmlSource.Html = ;//your html string here
      browser.Source = htmlSource;
  ```

Check [How to work with files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=windows) for more information.

Comment: What do I need to import for `LoadResourceText`?

Comment: Replace it with the name of your current class and also see to it that these images are in the same assembly as that of your current class.